# Convert CSV file to HTML and display in browser with Pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, web

How can I convert a `CSV` file to `HTML` and open it in a web browser via `Python` using `pandas`.
Below is my program but I can not display them in the web page:

```
import pandas
import webbrowser
data = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\issao\Downloads\data.csv')
data = data.to_html()
webbrowser.open('data.html')
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you just write a little introduction on what you want to do? People who could help you can be dissuaded if you doesn't precisely explain your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a `url` to `webbrowser`.

Save the html content into a local file and pass it's path to webbrowser

```
import os
import webbrowser
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\issao\Downloads\data.csv')
html = data.to_html()
path = os.path.abspath('data.html')
url = 'file://' + path

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few steps:

1. Pandas does not build a full HTML page but only a  element.

   `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}).to_html()`

   Returns: `<table border="1" class="dataframe">...</table>`
2. You need host the HTML somewhere and open a web browser. You can use a local file and do run the browser from python (`os.system('firefox page.html'`). But I doubt that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the OP's question directly, but for someone who is looking at an alternative to Pandas, they can check out csvtotable(https://github.com/vividvilla/csvtotable), especially the option with "--serve". Sample usage would be something like this: **csvtotable data.csv --serve**. This "serves" the CSV file to the browser.